# How do I solve this trigonometry word problem concerning sinusoidal functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

To my understanding, amplitude $= 70$ and angular frequency = $10\pi$. However, I don't know if it is a cosine/sine graph, and I'm not sure about the midline.

Can someone help me solve this math problem? Please help.

[image]

Comment: You should begin by identifying what the problem is asking.  By relying on a picture of the text that step has either been skipped or you expect us to read the problem to you.  I'd like to see you state the problem in your own words.  Only then will I consider helping you to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

At time $t = 0$, the wings are horizontal, so $y = 90^\circ$. Assume that the wings flap downward from horizontal and not upward.

Then at time $t = \frac{1}{4}(0.2)$ seconds, the wings will be in the lower position. Since there is an angle of $70^\circ$ below the horizontal, we know that $y = 160^\circ$.

Likewise, at time $t = \frac{3}{4}(0.2)$ seconds, the wings will be in the upper position. Since there is an angle of $70^\circ$ above the horizontal, we know that $y = 20^\circ$.

Putting everything together, we see that a sine graph would be convenient, and we obtain:
$$
y = 70\sin(10\pi t) + 90
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you clarify where you got 1/4 and 3/4 from?

Comment: Imagine the graph of a standard $y = \sin(t)$ function. It reaches its max value after a quarter period (at $t = \frac{1}{4}(2\pi)$, we have $y = 1$), and it reaches its min value after three quarter of a period (at $t = \frac{3}{4}(2\pi)$, we have $y = -1$).